# Find pair of elements in integer array such that abs(v[i]-v[j]) is minimized

Tags: c++, c, arrays

Lets say we have int array with 5 elements: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

What I need to do is to find minimum abs value of array's elements' subtraction:

We need to check like that

```
1-2   2-3  3-4   4-5

1-3   2-4  3-5

1-4   2-5

1-5
```

And find minimum abs value of these subtractions. We can find it with 2 `for`s. The question is, is there any algorithm for finding value with one and only `for`?

Comment: You don't need 2 fors. Find `max` and `min` and `max-min` will get you maximum difference.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to sort the array and find the two nearest adjacent values?

Comment: Yes. There is. But since it looks like homework it is better to think for your own.

Comment: I 100% failed to understand what it is you're doing -- is there a common colloquial term that describes the math in play?

Comment: @kirilloid - I think he's looking for the *minimum* difference.

Comment: @kirilloid I looking for minimum not max

Comment: I see. Then sort + loop as in 2nd comment. `O(N log N)` is better than `O(N*N)`

Comment: @epic_syntax - Is the array assumed to be sorted or can the elements be in any order (say: 2, 4, 3, 5, 1)?  The elements are sorted in the example you gave

Comment: @Attila not sorted. any order

Answer (score 1):

sort the list and subtract nearest two elements

Comment: Why the middle two.  If the list is sorted, the pair of minimum difference could still be anywhere, but they will be adjacent to each other.  Finding this pair requires a for loop.  Sorting requires at least one for.  How is this better than the naive approach?

Comment: That was a bit of a mistake but this approach is O(nlgn) rather than O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

The provably best performing solution is assymptotically **linear O(n)** up until constant factors.

This means that the time taken is proportional to the number of the elements in the array (which of course is the best we can do as we at least have to read every element of the array, which already takes O(n) time).

Here is one such O(n) solution (which also uses O(1) space if the list can be modified in-place):

```
int mindiff(const vector<int>& v)
{
    IntRadixSort(v.begin(), v.end());

    int best = MAX_INT;

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size()-1; i++)
    {
        int diff = abs(v[i]-v[i+1]);
        if (diff < best)
           best = diff;
    }

    return best;
}
```

IntRadixSort is a linear time fixed-width integer sorting algorithm defined here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

The concept is that you leverage the fixed-bitwidth nature of ints by paritioning them in a series of fixed passes on the bit positions.  ie partition them on the hi bit (32nd), then on the next highest (31st), then on the next (30th), and so on - which only takes linear time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is equivalent to sorting.  Any sorting algorithm could be used, and at the end, return the difference between the nearest elements.  A final pass over the data could be used to find that difference, or it could be maintained during the sort.  Before the data is sorted the min difference between adjacent elements will be an upper bound.

So to do it without two loops, use a sorting algorithm that does not have two loops.  In a way it feels like semantics, but recursive sorting algorithms will do it with only one loop.  If this issue is the n(n+1)/2 subtractions required by the simple two loop case, you can use an O(n log n) algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

No, unless you know the list is sorted, you need two

Answer (score -1):

Its simple Iterate in a for loop

```
       keep 2 variable "minpos and maxpos " and " minneg" and "maxneg"  
       check for the sign of the value you encounter and store maximum positive in maxpos
       and minimum +ve number in "minpos" do the same by checking in if case for number 
       less than zero. Now take the difference of maxpos-minpos in one variable and
       maxneg and minneg in one variable and print the larger of the two . You will get 
       desired.
```

I believe `you definitely know how to find max and min in one for loop`

```
correction :- The above one is to find max difference in case of minimum you need to 
             take max and second max instead of max and min :)
```

Comment: This solution works for finding maximum diff but does not work for minimum diff.  Your correction does not work. For example {4,5,10}.  max is 10, second max is 5.  This does not identify 4,5 as the correct pair.

Answer (score -1):

This might be help you:

```
end=4;
subtractmin;
m=0;
for(i=1;i<end;i++){
if(abs(a[m]-a[i+m])<subtractmin)
subtractmin=abs(a[m]-a[i+m];}
if(m<4){
m=m+1
end=end-1;
i=m+2;
}}
```

Comment: This is trying to find the maximum diff, the question asks for the minimum diff